# Extract region name from user query

Tags: javascript, node.js, nlp

I am using weather js npm module ([weather-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/weather-js)) to find weather of a region.

Everything works fine, I was trying to modify it based on user query.

As per the module, it only accepts **region name** in search parameter.How do I Modify it so that I can process it based on user input? Where user input can be in any element in query array.

**How do I extract region from user query and pass it to `weather.find`**

```
var weather = require('weather-js');
var query   = ["Weather of US" ,"Tell weather Of US", "US weather today" ,"What is US weather"], 
weather(query);
function weather(query){
  weather.find({search: query, degreeType: 'F'}, function(err, result) {
  if(err){
    err = 'temperature could not be fetched';
    return err;
  }
  var temp   = result[0].current.temperature;
  var fToCel = (temp - 32) * 5 / 9;
  return fToCel;
});
}
```

Comment: I guess you'd have to either tell the user what to specifically enter in the search field, or have a list of regions. Still, how do you know what to do when someone types `tell us what bay area weather is in mongolia`, is it "US", "Bay Area" or "Mongolia" ?

Comment: Exactly so i have to keep on extracting a particular region from user input until my weather.find returns a valid result @adeneo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried NER?

[image]
You can play with it [here](http://deagol.cs.illinois.edu:8080/).